# Error when copying a List in threaded code

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm getting an error on my threaded code when my machine is under heavy load.  When the machine is lightly loaded no error occurs.  I am using VS 2013, C# 5.0 and .NET 4.51.

The code looks like:

```
private static readonly Object lockGetData = new Object();

public static void GetData(string symbol, out List<Tuple<double, double>> velocityLine)
{
   try
   {
      lock (lockGetData)
      {
         mData = mSymbols[symbol];
         Debug.Assert(mData != null, "Oh crap! mData is null");
         velocityLine = new List<Tuple<double, double>>(mData.velocityLine);
         return;
      }
   } 
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      DebugPrint("GetData error.\n" + ex.Message, symbol);
      velocityLine = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
      return 0.0;
   } 
}
```

I am getting a error on the line:

```
velocityLine = new List<Tuple<double, double>>(mData.velocityLine);
```

The error message is: "Destination array was not long enough. Check destindex and length, and the array's lower bounds."

When the error occurs, and when I check the length of "velocityLine", it is null.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Comment: A length can't be null... but are you modifying `mData.velocityLine` in other threads? `List<T>` is not threadsafe.

Comment: look into [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is threadsafe

Comment: Also, you can't return `0.0` from a `void` method

Comment: What is the data type of `mData.velocityLine`?

Comment: Thank you. I will look into BlockingCollection.  You asked about the type of mData.velocityLine.  "mSymbols" is : public static Dictionary<string, MData> mSymbols = new Dictionary<string, MData>(); and MData is:       public class MData {
        public List<Tuple<double, double>> velocityLine { get; set; }
      }  The "return 0.0" is a mistake in my posting.  It is not in my acutal code.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the catch statement, and inspected "velocityLine".  The debugger reported that it was "null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a complete code example, it's not clear how the `mData` collection object is being used. But given the error, it's practically certain that the object is being modified by some other thread while the `List<T>` constructor is executing, with the result that the length of that collection changes between the time the `List<T>` constructor uses its length to initialize the backing array, and the time it then tries to copy all of the elements from the `mData` object to the backing array.

It is not sufficient to synchronize the `velocityLine` object. You must also synchronize any access to the `mData` object being used to initialize it.

Finally, I will note that it's extremely bad form here to have a `try/catch (Exception)` clause here (assuming your version actually has a valid `return` statement, as opposed to what's posted here). If you put it there just for the purpose of debugging this code, that's fine…but now that you know what's wrong, you should remove it. This will ensure that if there are any other bugs, you are forced to fix them instead of the program mysteriously just doing something different from what you wanted at random times.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I added a lock to another routine that was also accessing "mData", and that seems to solve the problem.